# Media player via flash stream attachment

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, flash

I'm trying to post a Flash media player (not Facebook's default MP3 player) as an attachment to a stream post. I can get the flash app to load, but it won't load the media file. Both the media file and .swf are hosted on my server. It works fine if I load the .swf from a test page hosted on my own server instead of in a Facebook feed.

The attachment is defined like this:

```
{media:[{
  type:"flash",
  imgsrc:"http://mysite.com/images/my-icon.png",
  swfsrc:"http://assets.mysite.com/files/wavplayer.swf?gui=mini&h=20&w=300&sound=test123.wav",
  width:40,height:40,expanded_width:40,expanded_height:40}]}
```

I'm not up on cross-domain Flash permissions; is there a recipe for getting this to work? Any way even to get debugging info on the Flash app in Firefox?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do be able debug flash movie in Firefox you need:

1. [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)
2. [Debug Flash Player](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html)
3. [Flash Bug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashbug/) (not sure if this addon will work with latest version of FF)

Some errors like broken link to media assets (audio, fonts, images), could be seen on Net tab of firebug. Debug Flash Player allow you to see errors of Flash movies, and if .swf was compiled in debug mode, you will be able to see all traces in the log of Flash Bug.